# Можно ли присваивать объекту, который уже был использован в move-семантике?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Предположим, есть код:

```
struct example  
{  
    example() {  
        ptr = new int(2);    
    }  
    example(example&& rhs) { 
        ptr = rhs.ptr;
        rhs.ptr = nullptr;  
    }  
    ~example()  {
        delete ptr;
    }  
    int a = 2;  
    char b = 'a';  
    int* ptr;  
};

int main()  
{  
    example e;  
    int* a = new int(1);  
    example move_e = std::move(e);  
    e = {1,'b', a};
}
```

Теперь вопрос: корректно ли после перемещения объекта `e` опять ему присваивать что-либо? Я знаю, что обращаться к полям после перемещения будет *undefined behavior*, но а если что-то присваивать объекту? Всё вроде законно, и после присваивания его поля снова будет можно использовать как `r-value`...

Прав ли я?

Comment: Кстати, UB быть не должно при обращении к членам перемещенного объекта.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Безусловно можно.

Есть даже [пример](http://eel.is/c++draft/utility.exchange#1) в черновике Стандарта:

```
T old_val = std::move(obj);
obj = std::forward<U>(new_val);
return old_val;
```

Ну и сама [выдержка](http://eel.is/c++draft/lib.types.movedfrom#1) из Стандарта про то, что представляет из себя перемещенный объект:

> Objects of **types defined in the C++ standard library** may be moved from ([class.copy]). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, **such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state**.

Т.е. такие объекты находятся в корректном, но неопределенном состоянии. В частности, все функции-члены такого объекта должны отрабатывать корректно, в том числе и оператор `=`.

---

Стоит обратить особое внимание, что указанная цитата относится к типам стандартной библиотеки. Для пользовательских классов программист сам задает состояние объекта после перемещения, т.к. сам же и пишет реализацию перемещающих функций.

---

[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7027695/3240681) на ответ на enSO.

При этом, чтобы Ваш код был [работоспособен](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/TSj5LxhnjcUE18cO), требуется добавить соответствующий конструктор и оператор присваивания (в данном случае подойдет перемещающий):

```
example(int a, char b, int* ptr) : a(a), b(b), ptr(ptr) {}
example& operator=(example&& o) { 
    a = o.a; b = o.b; ptr = o.ptr; o.ptr = nullptr; return *this; }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните что понимается под состоянием в данном случае? Судя по тексту у объекта может быть несколько корректных состояний, и стандарт требует чтобы после перемещения объект находился в обном из них, но не требует в каком конкретно. Поэтому оно неопределенное.

Comment: @Cerbo, я не очень Вас понял. Вы просите меня добавить в ответ часть Вашего комментария? Потому как вроде сами отвечаете на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Нет, я прошу вас пояснить в каких состояниях объект может находится после перемещения, и что вообще понимается под состоянием.

Comment: @Cerbo в первую очередь хочу заметить, что цитата из Стандарта применима к библиотечным классам. Понятно, что пользователь может написать какой угодно перемещающий конструктор, делающий что угодно. Например возьмем некий класс строки, неопределенное состояние после перемещения может подразумевать, что строка станет пустой, или останется прежней или ещё как-то изменится. Но при этом её интерфейсные функции должны работать корректным образом, например `length` вернет длину этой новой строки, а не какое-то случайное число.

Comment: @Cerbo Т.е. объект полностью жив и работоспособен, но чтобы выяснить его реальное состояние надо его опросить всевозможными get-функциями. И это состояние в общем случае никак не связано с имеющимся до перемещения состоянием.

Comment: То есть речь идет о "прикладных" состояниях, имеющих значение на прикладном уровне, а не на уровне языка. Я сперва понял текст так, что в нем речь идет о некоторых определенных стандартном состояниях. Теперь же, общий смысл цитаты в том, что разработчик в перемещающем конструкторе/операторе обязан позаботиться об объекте-источнике и не бросать его в некорректном состоянии?

Comment: @Cerbo бросить его в некорректном состоянии не получится, т.к. как минимум придется обеспечить правильность работы деструктора. Ведь перемещаемый объект не испаряется бесследно, и так или иначе будет когда-то уничтожен.

Comment: Мне кажется это нужно более четко отразить в ответе, типа: "да можно, но за это твечает разработчик так как этого стандарт требует". У вас написано так как буд-то объект сам по-волшебству переходит в корректное состояние.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения

Answer (score 4):

> Я знаю, что обращаться к полям после перемещения будет undefined behavior

Весьма сомнительное утверждение. Конструктор перемещения строится таким образом, чтобы последующий вызов деструктора (который, несомненно, обращается к полям) на объекте отработал корректно. Было бы весьма странно, если бы обращение к полям не из деструктора рассматривалось как UB (хотя стандарт я не смотрел). С другой стороны, объект обеспечит съедобное для деструктора состояние, но он не обязан обеспечивать цельное с точки зрения бизнес-логики состояние. Т. е. поле, которое при других условиях не может быть равно null, вполне может таковым оказаться. Об этом надо думать. Автор класса знает, как он его использует, а всем остальным стоит рассматривать такой объект просто как мусор.

> а если что-то присваивать объекту?

Не вижу причин, почему так было бы нельзя сделать.
Хотя, если разработчик класса очень постарается, то и на этом можно что-то плохое словить.