# Что происходит с объектом после std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

Пример класса:

```
class Move
{
   public:
   Move(std::string name) : name(name) {};
   Move(Move&& move) : name(std::move(move.name)) {};
   void Set(std::string&& add)
   {
      this->name.append(add);
   }
   void Print()
   {
      std::cout << this->name << std::endl;
   }

private:
   std::string name;
};
```

После выполнения данного кода:

```
Move move0("string");
Move move1 = std::move(move0);
```

объект `move0` будет иметь вид `{name=""}`, но `""` пустая `std::string` все равно занимает место в памяти и не освобождает ее сама по себе. Получается, что перемещение более эффективное в некоторых случаях, но при этом старые ссылки остаются "доживать" свой век? Не понятно, что происходит с объектами после использования на них `std::move`, хотя казалось бы, что они должны становиться `nullptr`.

**UPD**

Почему есть ситуации  в которых после `std::move` объект из которого было произведено перемещение, остается без изменений?

```
int main()
{
   std::string str = " Another";
   m.Set(std::move(str));
   return 0;
}
```

После `std::move(str)`, сам `str` остался без изменений.

Comment: Объект не может становиться nullptr потому что он не указатель.

Comment: @Qwertiy  окей, а что тогда с ним происходит? Он  просто остается висеть "пустым" в памяти? (обновил вопрос).

Comment: `std::move` по факту — это просто приведение типа, она не делает ничего... всю работу делает функция, куда передаётся r-value ссылка. Если она грамотно написана, то она оставит переданный объект в корректном состоянии, таком, что его, как минимум, можно будет передать деструктору и ничего не сломать. Все стандартные функции в этом отношении написаны «корректно».

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Можно ли присваивать объекту, который уже был использован в move-семантике?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/545894/176217)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С++ - это вам не Java. В нем объекты не могут быть null, и не являются ссылками.

> что происходит с объектами после использования на них std::move

Строго говоря, `move` ничего не делает, кроме как превращает выражение в rvalue ("маскирует" под временную переменную). Это влияет в первую очередь на разрешение перегрузок, и в том числе заставляет срабатывать перемещающие конструктор и оператор присваивания, вместо копирующих. Изменения в объекте вызываются именно перемещающими конструктором или оператором присваивания, куда он передается как аргумент (если это вообще происходит).

Что конкретно происходит с объектом после перемещения из него - зависит того, как написаны перемещающие конструктор и оператор присваивания.

Про стандартные контейнеры, например, говорят что они "are left in valid, but unspecified state". В большинстве реализаций они становятся пустыми, но это не гарантируется.

> казалось бы, что они должны становиться nullptr.

Объекты нельзя "сделать nullptr", но можно переформулировать вопрос:

*Почему перемещение из объекта не уничтожает его, и требуется дополнительный вызов на нем деструктора?*

Я так понимаю, потому что это очень усложнило бы работу компилятора.

Например, для

```
void foo(std::string s)
{
    // ...
}
```

деструктор всегда вызывается для `s` при возврате из функции.

А если перемещение из объекта уничтожало бы его, то компилятору потребовалось бы отслеживать, какие переменные перемещаются, а какие нет. Если переменные перемещаются при определенном условии, то пришлось бы запоминать для каждого объекта, был он перемещен или нет, и в зависимости от этого вызывать или не вызывать на нем деструктор  при выходе из функции. Это выглядит сложно.

Comment: Логично. Теперь понятно.
И да, хорошо подметили про `null`. До того как перейти на С++ работал 3 года на джаве и еще остались нюансы, которые иногда мешают как в работе так и понимании, казалось бы, простых вещей.

Comment: Не только отслеживание аргументов, есть же ещё delete, который тоже деструктор вызывает. А ещё delete[] - если поперемещать элементы из массива, то вообще жесть будет это отследить.

Answer (score 6):

В языке С++ нет никакой встроенной семантики перемещения. В языке С++ есть только rvalue-ссылки, категории результатов выражений, и связанные с ними правила overload resolution. А что вы сами "слепите" из этих базовых свойств языка - семантику перемещения или что-то другое - определяется только вашим кодом (или, соответственно, библиотечным кодом).

Вы передали переменную `str` в метод `Set` по rvalue-ссылке, ни внутри метода `Set` вы только *копируете* полученный аргумент `add` и никакого физического перемещения данных из него даже и не пытаетесь делать.

Если вы "надеетесь" получить физическое перемещение из `add` внутри метода `Set`, то это ваша задача - разрешить методу `std::string::append` переместить данные из своего аргумента

```
void Set(std::string&& add)
{
  this->name.append(std::move(add));
}
```

Но и в этом случае фактическое перемещение данных из `add` произойдет только в том случае, если сам метод `std::string::append` примет решение выполнить перемещение. И здесь я вам могу сказать по секрету, что метод `std::string::append` в принципе никогда ничего не перемещает. В большинстве применений `std::string::append` это просто-напросто невозможно. Оптимизировать `std::string::append` через физическое перемещение возможно только в том случае, когда строка-получатель изначально пуста. А это слишком частная ситуация, чтобы ее оптимизировать. (Я бы лично, возможно, это сделал, но разработчики класса `std::string` рассудили по-другому.)

И постарайтесь уяснить, что в С++ обычное копирование - это тоже один из вариантов перемещения. Поэтому рассуждения вроде "объект остался неизменным, значит перемещения не произошло" - бессмысленны.