# Есть ли необходимость вызывать clear для контейнера после его мува, если планируется повторное использование?

Tags: c++, стандарт, move, containers

**Вот пример:**

```
for (std::string key, value; true;)
{
    if (!std::getline(stream,key,':')) break;
    if (!std::getline(stream,value))   break;

    /* implementation */

    map.emplace(std::move(key),std::move(value));

    key.clear();   // ?
    value.clear(); // ?
}
```

Есть мнение, что стандарт не гарантирует валидности внутреннего состояния контейнера после мува. Ответов в сети как-то не нашёл. Хотелось бы прояснить данный вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: Стандарт гарантирует, что состояние будет корректным для вызова деструктора, но каким именно - ничего не говорится. *Если не ошибаюсь*.

Comment: @Harry а может [синонимизируем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/language-lawyer/synonyms)?

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/545894/176217), и в чём-то может даже дубликат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После перемещения контейнер остаётся в корректном состоянии, но в каком именно не специфицируется (*valid but unspecified*). В своём ответе @Harry [привёл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1265918) соответствующую цитату из стандарта языка ([lib.types.movedfrom](http://eel.is/c++draft/lib.types.movedfrom)).

Что это за состояние такое, «корректное, но не специфицированное», в стандарте также есть пояснение. [defns.valid](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.valid):

> **valid but unspecified state**
>
> ⟨library⟩ value of an object that is not specified except that the object's invariants are met and operations on the object behave as specified for its type
>
> [*Example 1*: If an object `x` of type `std​::​vector<int>` is in a valid but unspecified state, `x.empty()` can be called unconditionally, and `x.front()` can be called only if `x.empty()` returns `false`. — *end example*]

Таким образом, в вашем случае объекты `key` и `value` типа `std::string` после перемещения находятся в корректном состоянии.
Можно даже вызвать метод [`empty()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty), для проверки строк на пустоту, он гарантированно вернёт либо `false`, либо `true`, но что именно — не специфицируется.

Чтобы не было никаких неожиданностей при повторном использовании перемещённого контейнера, необходимо явно привести его в какое-нибудь конкретное состояние. Например, опустошить с помощью `clear()`. Также перемещённую строку можно смело передавать для заполнения в [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), т.к. данная функция перед записью чего-либо в строку очищает её.

Answer (score 1):

О, нашел! `[lib.types.movedfrom]`. Выделено мной.

> Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a **valid** but **unspecified** state.

Так что если в контейнере после перемещения что-то останется, то это так же разрешено и нормально, как и если он будет пуст.

Обещают только, по сути, что не будет неприятностей типа пустого контейнера, для которого `size()` вернет ненулевое число или что-то наподобие этого.

P.S. Ну, а для чтения ничего чистить не надо - все равно при корректном чтении строка будет *перезаписана*.

Comment: Cppreference пишет, что вектор после мува пустой. *"Unless otherwise specified"* Видимо для вектора оно таки specified, но я пока не нашел где.

Answer (score 1):

Это краткая выжимка из [Is a moved-from vector always empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17735913/2752075) на английском SO. Подробности см. там.

---

После перемещения оригинальный вектор будет пуст, как минимум если используется стандартный аллокатор. Это не гарантируется стандартом явно, но это единственная разумная вещь, которую могут делать реализации стандартной библиотеки.

Это неявно следует из того, что:

- Перемещающий конструктор и оператор присваивания должны иметь сложность O(1).
- Для вектора запрещен аналог [short string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319672/2752075) (неявно, потому что `std::swap` для вектора обязан не инвалидировать итераторы на элементы), следовательно все элементы всегда должны быть в куче.

Поэтому единственное разумное поведение перемещающих операций - это оставить оригинальный вектор пустым.