# Становится ли ссылка на строку невалидной после её мува?

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, ссылки, итераторы

На [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) написано, что после move assignment строки ссылки на неё становятся невалидными. Правда ли это? Или всё таки имелось в виду, что ссылки на внутренние элементы строки типа `str.c_str()` стали другими?

```cpp
auto& s3 = s1;
s2 = std::move(s1);
// is s3 still valid?
```

Comment: А проверить религия не позволяет?... https://ideone.com/oEAmvd

Comment: @Harry не понимаю, что доказывает этот пример. В нём нет ни итераторов, ни указателей, ни ссылок...

Comment: @Harry, там сказано "may be invalidated". Работающий пример ничего не может сделать с такой формулировкой. У вас работает, у меня нет. У вас сейчас работает, потом перестанет.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy так там ссылок нет, какая разница?

Comment: Я возразил не против конкретного примера (вы правы, он ничего не проверяет), а против самого принципа проверки.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Это пример, где она стала невалидной. Этого достаточно, чтобы предполагать худшее :)

Comment: @Harry, строка не стала невалидной. Она стала пустой, что нормально для аргумента перемещающего конструктора.

Comment: Я не нашёл в стандарте подтверждения. Ждём @wololo .

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я неверно выразился; невалидным объект при перемещении стать не может. Имел в виду, что стал не тем, каким был раньше.

Comment: @Harry, я с вами согласен. Дальше: в стандарте прямо сказано что указатели внутрь контейнера переживают перемещение самого контейнера. Вопрос: для строк есть такая же гарантия? Я в стандарте не нашёл обратного. Но я уже ошибался и не раз. Жду настоящего сварщика.

Comment: Думаю, что во фразе `references, pointers, and iterators to str may be invalidated` подразумевается, что инвалидироваться могут итераторы не **на** `str`, а **в** (т.е. внутрь / на элементы контейнера) `str`. В черновике стандарта описание более прозрачное. [string.cons/25](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/string.cons#25): `Effects: Move assigns as a sequence container, except that iterators, pointers and references may be invalidated.` Хотя тут снова не говорится явным образом, что речь об элементах контейнера, а не самом контейнере, но по-моему это ясно из контекста.

Comment: Но на всякий случай обратимся к ещё одному пункту стандарта, в котором уже точно речь идёт об элементах строки. [string.require/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/string.require#4): `References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a basic_­string sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that basic_­string object: Passing as an argument to any standard library function taking a reference to non-const basic_­string as an argument.228 ... 228) For example, as an argument to non-member functions swap() ... or as an argument to basic_­string​::​swap().`

Comment: Подытоживая, в вашем примере после перемещения строки `s1` ссылка `s3` валидна и указывает на объект `s1` находящийся в корректном, но неспецифицированном состоянии.

Comment: @wololo fixed, thx

Comment: @Никита https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1):

Перемещённый объект (после move assignment) остаётся в валидном, но неизвестном состоянии (см. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545897/176217)). Т.о. ссылка s3 валидна и указывает на тот же объект s1. Но сам объект s1 уже может быть изменён.

Написанное на cppreference:

> Replaces the contents with those of str using SequenceContainer's move assignment semantics.
> Unlike other sequence container move assignments, references, pointers, and iterators to elements of str may be invalidated.

относится к элементам строки, по аналогии с элементами последовательного контейнера, если строку рассматривать как контейнер символов.

Потенциальная дополнительная инвалидация итераторов, указателей и ссылок (на элементы строки) обусловлена вероятным использованием short string optimization.

Comment: `Написанное на cppreference: ... references, pointers, and iterators to elements of str may be invalidated. относится к элементам строки`. Теперь, то понятно, что относится к элементам строки. На момент написания вопроса на cppreference было написано следующее: `references, pointers, and iterators to str may be invalidated`, что, конечно, может сбить с толку.

Comment: @wololo я сразу и не заметил, что текст обновился, почитал комменты, пошёл по ссылкам на SequenceContainer смотреть. А в ответе уже, получается, обновлённую часть процитировал.